# Cannot create an instance of class lifeycle dependancy error

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, runtime-error, retrofit2, android-viewmodel

when I try to open my application I recieved following error
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class

com.eprogrammers.ayesh.musicvideos.ui.MovieList.MovieViewModel`

this is viewmodel

```
package com.eprogrammers.ayesh.musicvideos.ui.MovieList

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.eprogrammers.ayesh.musicvideos.data.api.model.Data
import com.eprogrammers.ayesh.musicvideos.data.repositery.MovieRepo
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class MovieViewModel  @Inject constructor(
    val MovieRepo:MovieRepo
):ViewModel(){
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(emptyList<Data>())
    val state:StateFlow<List<Data>>
        get() = _state
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val Movies = MovieRepo.getMovies()
            _state.value = Movies

        }
    }

}
```

this is how i got data

```
        val MovieViewModel = viewModel(modelClass = MovieViewModel::class.java)
        val state by MovieViewModel.state.collectAsState()
```

I tried to get json data with retrofit and show them with Lazy Grid